# Fabric.js some custom fonts render in very small size and in wrong font

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, fabricjs

I'm working on a solution for lazy loading fonts and using the on a fabric.js canvas. I am hosting custom fonts in woff format and loading them using the WebFont loader on change event of a select box like this:

```
$fontSelect.change(function() {
            const [font] = $(this).select2('data');
            if (font) {
                FontLoader.load(font.url, font.text)
                    .then(() => {
                        editorObject.setFontFamily(font.text);
                    }, () => {
                        console.log('error while loading font');
                    });
            }
        });
```

The FontLoader.load method looks like this:

```
private static loadCustomFont(name: string, url: string, callback: Function, errorCallback: Function): void {

        if (this.loadedFonts.indexOf(name) !== -1) {
            callback();
            return;
        }
        const markup = `
            @font-face {
                font-family: '${name}';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: normal;
                src: local('${name}'), url('${url}') format('woff');
            }
        `;
        let style =  document.createElement('style');
        style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        style.innerHTML = markup;
        document.head.appendChild(style);

        WebFont.load({
            custom: {
                families: [
                    name
                ]
            },
            active: () => {
                callback();
            },
            inactive: () => {
                errorCallback();
            }
        });
    }
```

Most of the fonts work correctly, but some of them render in the following way:

[image]

The font in question is Dumbledore 3. It is available for free on dafont.com.

The odd thing is that when I go to dev tools and specify font-family on some element in css the font is displayed properly.

One of the other problematic fonts is also Disco Duck 3D.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the font name.
The font name get passed to ctx.font api, the number in the font name get mistaken for font-size

Try to pass the font to fabric.js like

```
fontFamily = '"Disco Duck 3D"';
```

And you should be fine